# CSS expand text downward with rotate?

Tags: css, transform

I've rotated some text -90deg, but if I increase the text length, it expands "upward" (ie. right, with a -90deg rotation), but I'd like the text to expand downward (ie. kind of like a 90deg rotations instead of -90deg, but I still want the -90deg orientation).

Here's what's I'm looking at:

[image]

Here's my html and css:

```
<div class="header"><div class="wrapper"><span>Products</span></div></div>

.section > .header { display: block; position: relative; float: left; font-size: 48pt;      width: 157px; height: 100%; }
.section > .header > .wrapper { width: 100%; height: 100%; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg); }
.section > .header > .wrapper > span { display: block; position: relative; left: 25px; height: 100%;
}
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS? I've tried a bunch of things (rotating the wrapper, and then reverse-rotating the inner span, aligning the text right), and other stuff, to no avail.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Have you thought about using images?.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. I also heard of a language called Javascript. I'm wondering if it's possible in CSS.

Comment: Also relevant: [tag:svg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:
(needed to do the text-align a little more properly)

```
.section > .header > .wrapper { display:block; text-align: right; }
.section > .header > .wrapper > span { display: block; -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); height: 100px;  width: 600px; position: relative; top: 260px; left: -180px; }
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by decreasing the `left` value of `.header > .wrapper > span`

[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/L4YXX/)

In that i changed the left value to `-120px`

```
.section > .header > .wrapper > span { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    left: -120px; //changed the value
    height: 100%;
}​
```

Comment: This does not solve it. My fault for not having a proper initial left value (-120px is the right left for the first text, "Products"), but I want any text longer than this to expand down to the bottom of the page, not to the top (past the header, as it does now). At the moment I'd have to change the specific left value of each header span depending on it's individual width, only because I can't figure out a way to have the text expand left/down.